# How to check whether Web-to-Case and Web-to-Lead is set up in the Salesforce org

Tags: web2lead, web2case

Hi I am new to the Salesforce W2C and W2L. I need to check whether a W2C or W2L is setup in Salesforce in our company by the previous developer. How can I find it. Since we have got mail from sales force for the W2C and W2L summer '17 upgrade. I have studied the document clearly and to my knowledge there was no W2C or W2L is setup in the Salesforce Org. Is there any other way to check whether W2C and W2L is setup in Salesforce org.

Please Advice.

Comment: Have you had a look on the web-to-lead setup page to see if it's been enabled?

Comment: Yes I would see the Web to Lead is Enabled. but Web-to Case is showing like a record and has option to save .